# Should this be solved using a subset sum algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

The problem is asking me to find all possible subsets of a list that added together (in pairs, alone, or multiple of them) will equal a given number. I have been reading a lot on subset sum problems and not sure if this applies to this problem.

To explain the problem more, I have a max weight of candy that I am allowed to purchase.
I know the weight of ten pieces of different candy that I have stored in a list

```
candy = [ [snickers, 150.5], [mars, 130.3], ......]
I can purchase at most max_weight = 740.5 grams EXACTLY.
```

Thus I have to find all possible combinations of candy that will equal exactly the max_weight. I will be programming in python. Don't need the exact code but just whether or not it is a subset sum problem and possible suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: this is known as "the knapsack problem"

Comment: No, I thought it might be knapsack at first glance, but there's no value to optimize.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the knapsack problem. There is no value associated with the candies, nor is there an upperbound on the weight. The weight seems to be an exact constraint and not an upper-bound constraint. So I'd say this /is/ a subset sum problem

Comment: ahh I stand corrected apparently :P

Comment: How many candies of each type are you allowed to purchase? If it's only one, this is subset sum. Otherwise, it's a more general integer linear programming problem.

Comment: Only one per each type per subset that gives the exact max_weight.

Comment: Is brute force feasible? ``itertools.combinations`` could be used: ``[combinations(candy, i) for i in range(len(candy)]``

Comment: @Dietrich but wouldn't this only return a solution in pairs of candy instead of 1,2,3,4 ... types that summed give the max_weight?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Subset sum can be reduced to Knapsack by assigning `value = weight` for every item.

Comment: @NiklasB. Not sure I understand what you mean exactly. Could you try to explain in other terms. Thank you!

Comment: @user3245453: I'm just saying that subset sum is a special case of knapsack.

Comment: @user3245453 Are you allowed to purchase an item multiple times?

Comment: Also, is there some bound on the number of digits of your weights?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes you can purchase an item as many times as you'd like a s long as it appears in each possible subset at most one time!

Comment: @NiklasB. It can have two decimal places but the second one will always be a zero so it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Ok. Just enumerate all the subsets using `itertools.combinations` then, like Dietrich suggested and filter the invalid solutions out. But don't use floats, multiply by 100 and cast to int first. Otherwise you won't ever get *exactly* the given sum due to floating point imprecision (most decimals cannot be represented exactly in binary)

Comment: @NiklasB. Last question, will I be able to place in a list also the candy names, whose prices are part of each subset? Thank you! and Thank you everyone for all of your help! Really made me understand a lot more.

Comment: @user3245453: Yeah, combinations will generate subsets as lists of `[name, price]` tuples. You add up the prices and if the total price matches `max_weight`, you output the names.

Comment: Thank you again all! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's a brute force approach exploiting numpy's index magic:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

candy = [ ["snickers", 150.5], ["mars", 130.3], ["choc", 10.0]]

n = len(candy)
ww = np.array([c[1] for c in candy]) # extract weights of candys
idx = np.arange(n) # list of indexes

iidx,sums = [],[]
# generate all possible sums with index list
for k in range(n):
    for ii in combinations(idx, k+1):
        ii = list(ii) # convert tupel to list, so it can be used as a list of indeces
        sums.append(np.sum(ww[ii]))
        iidx.append(ii)
sums = np.asarray(sums)
ll = np.where(np.abs(sums-160.5)<1e-9)  # filter out values which match 160.5

# print results
for le in ll:
    print([candy[e] for e in iidx[le]])
```

Comment: as Niklas B. pointed out, it will probably be more accurate and I actually realized, easier if I just multiply by 100 every weight and max_weight and parse to int so that there won't be any errors due to floating point imprecision. Is that what your <1e-9 is referring to?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding these two lines of code. Could you possibly help me.                                                   for ii in combinations(idx, k+1):
        ii = np.ravel(ii)

Comment: Concerning ``<1-9`` you are totally right -  1e-9 is an  arbitrary but reasonable choice. ``combinations`` return a tuple, but numpy wants lists or np.arrays as index set. ``np.ravel`` is one possibility of proper conversions. Updated the code to use ``list()``

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the subset sum problem. You could use [a dynamic programming approach to solve it](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/)

Comment: Note that we need to multiply by a common divisor to make all the weights integral. `100` seems to be sufficient for this input, but it's a bit strange that imprecise floats are used to represent the weights.

Comment: Oh and if there's really only 10 elements, brute force might well be the better choice because `2^10 = 1024` is reasonably small